# python dask dataframes - concatenate groupby.apply output to a single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, dask

I am using dask dataframe.groupby().apply() 
and get a dask series as a return value. 
I am each group to a list triplets such as (a,b,1) and wish then to turn all the triplets into a single dask data frame

I am using this code in the end of the mapping function to return the triplets as a dask df

```
#assume here that trips is a generator for tripletes such as you would produce from itertools.product([l1,l2,l3])
trip = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(trip))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(trip)
return dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1)
```

then when I try to use something similar to [pandas concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [dask concatenate](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-stack.html)

Assume the result of the apply function is the variable result. 
I am trying to use 
import dask.dataframe as dd 
dd.concat(result, axis=0

and get the error

> raise TypeError("dfs must be a list of DataFrames/Series objects")
>   TypeError: dfs must be a list of DataFrames/Series objects

But when I check for the type of result using

```
print type(result)
```

I get

> output: class 'dask.dataframe.core.Series'

What is the proper way to apply a function over groups of dask groupby object and get all the results into one dataframe?

Thanks

edit:--------------------------------------------------------------
in order to produce the use case, assume this fake data generation

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
people = [[random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3), random.randint(1,3)] for i in range(1000)]
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame.from_records(people, columns=["first name", "last name", "cars"]), npartitions=1)
```

Now my mission is to group people by first and last name (e.g all the people with same first name & first last name) and than I need to get a new dask data frame which will contain how many cars each group had.

Assume that the apply function can return either a series of lists of tuples e.g [(name,name,cars count),(name,name,cars count)] or a data frame with the same columns - name, name, car count.

Yes, I know that particular use case can be solved in another way, but please trust me, my use case is more complex. But i can not share the data and can not generate any similar data. so let's use a dummy data :-)

The challenge is to connect all the results of the apply into a single dask data frame (pandas data frame will be a problem here, data will not fit in memory - so transitions via a pandas data frame will be a problem)

Comment: It seems output of your function is `Series`, so `concat` is not necessary. If get `MultiIndex` then `reset_index` should help for `DataFrame` like `dataframe.groupby().apply(func).reset_index()`.

Comment: @jezrael when I try to use result.reset_index().compute() i get - raise NotImplementedError(). what am i missing here?

Comment: Can you create come [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with input data and output? Without data hard find solution.

Comment: Thank you, and your function is in first code paragrapg, only `def(func):` is necessary?

Comment: @jezrael - thanks you! this is the relevant code from the function, I am well aware of python syntax demands :-) the real code is much more complex in order to fit my real data, this is the relevant part for the dummy data.

Comment: hmm, can you help me create same triple sample generator to your function? Thanks

Comment: Ive posted an edit over the op. Look at the comment above the code snippet. Its written there
@jezrael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working if output of `apply` is `pandas DataFrame`, so last if necessary convert to `dask DataFrame`:

```
def f(x):
    trip = ((1,2,x) for x in range(3))
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(trip)
    return df

df1 = ddf.groupby('cars').apply(f, meta={'x': 'i8', 'y': 'i8', 'z': 'i8'}).compute()
#only for remove MultiIndex
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   cars  level_1  x  y  z
0     1        0  1  2  0
1     1        1  1  2  1
2     1        2  1  2  2
3     2        0  1  2  0
4     2        1  1  2  1
5     2        2  1  2  2
6     3        0  1  2  0
7     3        1  1  2  1
8     3        2  1  2  2

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1,npartitions=1)
print (ddf1)
                cars level_1      x      y      z
npartitions=1                                    
0              int64   int64  int64  int64  int64
8                ...     ...    ...    ...    ...
Dask Name: from_pandas, 1 tasks
```

EDIT:

```
L = []
def f(x):
    trip = ((1,2,x) for x in range(3))
    #append each
    L.append(da.from_array(np.array(list(trip)), chunks=(1,3)))

ddf.groupby('cars').apply(f, meta={'x': 'i8', 'y': 'i8', 'z': 'i8'}).compute()
dar =  da.concatenate(L, axis=0)
print (dar)
dask.array<concatenate, shape=(12, 3), dtype=int32, chunksize=(1, 3)>
```

Comment: It worked! awesome! I feel that the main difference was the difference meta you gave it, which did the trick, there is still a small issue, i can't convert to pd data frame due to the memory bound, how can i remove the multi index without doing so?

Comment: In pandas is used `group_keys=False` in `groupby`, in dask not sure if it working...

Comment: i can't find any reference about is it already working or not, care to shed some light?

Comment: Give me some time, I am going to test it.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not implemented in dask :(

Comment: so for now there is no way to use groupby.apply and then combine all the results to a single dask dataframe without blowing up the memory? maybe an iterative approach? @jezrael

Comment: Unfortunately i have not a lot of experience with dask, so answer is not sure. dask api is simplify as pandas, so it seems this is non implemented :( But I have idea - is possible create `dask.array` in loop and then `concat`.

Comment: I add it to answer, but not sure if this is memory efficient solution... Maybe the best is ask author of dask in [github](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues)

Comment: when I try to use dask.array.concatenate(series,axis=0) i get not implemented error... how did it work for you?

Comment: I see your new question :( I am totaly lost :(

Answer (score 2):

For your edit:

```
In [8]: ddf.groupby(['first name', 'last name']).cars.count().compute()
Out[8]:
first name  last name
1           1            107
            2            107
            3            110
2           1            117
            2            120
            3             99
3           1            119
            2            103
            3            118
Name: cars, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you expain how that concetenates a series of dask dataframes created by map or apply without pandas blowing up the memory?

Comment: What do you mean by "series of dask dataframes"? I don't see anything in your example about that. Could you update your question to be clearer?